# How can I use an scss file in my reactjs app?

Tags: reactjs, sass, webpack-2

I am just getting to know the webpack2 and I am trying to use the scss loader in the webpackconfiguration, this is part of the modules.rules array(I googled a bit because I could not find how to do it from the webpackhomepage):

```
{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader:   ExtractTextPlugin.extract({ fallback: 'style-loader', use: 'css-loader' })
}
```

When I run the webpack-dev-server it compiles successfully however the app does not displaying anything and the (chrome)console returns this error:

```
Uncaught Error: [HMR] Hot Module Replacement is disabled.
    at eval (webpack:///../~/webpack/hot/dev-server.js?:51)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:475)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.bundle.js:20)
    at eval (webpack:///multi_../~/webpack-dev-server/client?:2)
    at Object.<anonymous> (vendor.bundle.js:1225)
    at __webpack_require__ (vendor.bundle.js:20)
    at vendor.bundle.js:66
    at vendor.bundle.js:69
```

How can I run an scssfile in my webpack2 app? Link to the [code](https://github.com/dimitri-a/webpack2_stuff)

Answer (score 0):

You're missing sass-loader in that config. See its readme for instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Install sass-loader first

```
npm install --save sass-loader
```

then add it to your webpack for loading .scss file type

e.g

```
    {
        test    : /\.scss?$/,
        loader  : ExtractTextPlugin.extract("style-loader", "css-loader!autoprefixer-loader!sass-loader"),
        include : path.join(__dirname, 'sass')
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this-->

```
>       {
>         test: /\.scss$/,
>         loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract( "css-loader?sourceMap!postcss-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap")
>       },
```